# Spring Data JPA and Read-Only Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently implementing a Springboot Microservice where the underlying database has a structure like the following one:

- A primary Entity (let's call it `Foo`) which has it's own ID, some attributes and a attribute which is a ForeignKey to another Entity (`Bar`), let's call this attribute `foreignKeyBarId`.
- A child entity `Bar` which has it's own id, the one referenced by `Foo` and another field. This entity must not have inserts or updates via the microservice since it is maintained externally and has just codes and descriptions which change once every many years.

When I want to read `Foo` via a Spring repository, implementing my repository which extends in example `JpaRepository`, I want to retrieve also the second attribute of `Bar` and this can be easily achieved by specifying the correct relationships between the entities via, like in my case, `@ManyToOne` annotation on `foreignKeyBarId` in `Foo`.

The big problem arises when I want to insert or update a Foo Object. In this case if the value in the `foreignKeyBarId` attribute is correct everything goes well, but if a "wrong" value is inserted a `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException` is thrown.

I've already tried with `@Immutable` annotation from hibernate on `Bar` entity but it just avoids updates queries on `Bar` entity.

Is there an easy way to solve this issue?

EDIT: cannot share the actual code but the issue can be seen using the following entities

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "bar")
public class BarEntity {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "description", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String desc;
}
```

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class FooEntity {

    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "some_attribute")
    private String someAttribute;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private BarEntity bar;
}
```

This means that `Bar` entity is mapped to a lookup table that the microservice will only read when reading the `Foo` entity, but it will never get written to by the microservice.

Additionally when creating a `Foo` inside the database either the Bar is null or it must actually be mapped to one entry that is already existing.

Comment: It might rely on wether you are making the right usage of the @ManyToOne relationship, could you provide the code for these entities ?

Comment: To me, it seems your `Bar` entity is parent while `Foo` is child. Is it so?

Comment: If something is just codes and descriptions, it sounds like a lookup table value, not an entity. Treating it like an entity just causes complications.

Comment: Yes it is exactly a lookup table, is there a way to code and use it without writing multiple repository and/or queries?